# heating system backwards?

Tags: pex, heat

I have an outdoor wood boiler about 40' from my house.  It is piped to a heat exchanger on the water tank, and then to the oil furnace(doesn't burn oil). I think the supply and return have been switched where they enter the foundation. Is this a problem?

Comment: Is all the piping the same size?

Comment: It is all 1" pex returned after the heat exchangers right back to the boiler. It may be flowing down into  the top of the modine heater and out the bottom though.

Comment: Depends on whether the exchangers have been set up counterflow or not. i.e. the hottest boiler water should meet the hottest stored water as opposed to meeting the coldest stored water, to maximize heat transfer. IME, the usual problem with they way those are usually plumbed is that the line from the boiler to the house acts as a heat exchanger due to poor insulation between the supply and return pipes, limiting heat transfer from the boiler to the house, but that has nothing to do with your question.